# Cartoon about a man and an RV. An episode had robot cat

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

There's this cartoon show about an old man and his RV. There's this talking pizza guy and a lot of different characters but he's the only one I remember.

I remember there was one episode where a cat went missing and then they found it but it was actually a robot so they had to kill it. Don't worry, they found the real cat.

Comment: not sure, but was it https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjtltrPnvb8AhU3zTgGHU9-CMcQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUncle_Grandpa&usg=AOvVaw3-zYl7HUv82mKfT1QUkM1j??

Comment: @shanu That is defintely a good match. And i think the episode "The Return of Aunt Grandma" is the one with the robot cat.

Comment: I hope you guys don't mind that I went ahead and converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by shanu and Bjorn Eriksson, this may be *[Uncle Grandpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Grandpa)*.

[image: Main characters in Uncle Grandpa: from left to right: Uncle Grandpa and Belly Bag, Pizza Steve, Mr. Gus and Giant Realistic Flying Tiger (bottom)]

> Uncle Grandpa, a magical shapeshifting humanoid, stops by children's houses every day to see how they are doing. The children he visits have a problem of their own and Uncle Grandpa tries to help them through a series of chaotic and surreal misadventures. He is a clowny sort of person who sometimes eats inedible objects (paper, and mostly books). He drives/lives in a UG-2000 model robotic RV known as the Perpetual Persistence and is accompanied by a talking red fanny pack named Belly Bag, a green dinosauroid named Mr. Gus, a static photographic cutout of a tiger named Giant Realistic Flying Tiger, and an anthropomorphic pepperoni pizza slice named Pizza Steve. He greets everybody using “Good Morning.”

### Opening

The episode involving the robot cat would be "[The Return of Aunt Grandma](https://uncle-grandpa.fandom.com/wiki/The_Return_of_Aunt_Grandma)" (bolding mine):

> .... Uncle Grandpa puts away the piece of bread and hears a cat meowing in the nearby dumpster, he takes the cat out and tells it that he's probably not much help to him and he gives the cat his bread crumb. The cat instantly likes Uncle Grandpa, Uncle Grandpa tells the cat it was nothing, Uncle Grandpa then checks the name tag to see who the cat is and he sees the cat's name is "Pickles", he tells Pickles that's a good name. Uncle Grandpa hears a kid calling for Pickles around the corner and he sees Aunt Grandma and hides behind the building, Aunt Grandma gives "Pickles" to the little boy and tells him to leave a good review on the website, Uncle Grandpa notices the other cat is named Pickles too and he thinks it's an uncanny coincidence. The boy says goodbye to Aunt Grandma and tells her he loves her, Uncle Grandpa believes something fishy is going on, the kid is happy to see "Pickles" again and Uncle Grandpa runs up to him claiming to have found Pickles, the boy doesn't know what he's talking about as Aunt Grandma gave him Pickles, Uncle Grandpa shows the boy the tag and swears that he has the real Pickles. The boy tells Uncle Grandpa to get away from him, Uncle Grandpa swaps the cats and tells him that the "Pickles" he's holding isn't the real Pickles, Uncle Grandpa checks the name tag of "Pickles" and sees that it's also named Pickles. The boy tells him of course that's Pickles and Uncle Grandpa tells the boy again that this isn't is cat, Uncle Grandpa believes he knows what's going on and the boy begins to call the cops on Uncle Grandpa if he doesn't give back Pickles, Uncle Grandpa tells the kid that this isn't Pickles and he's going to prove it by ripping of the head. The fake Pickles shorts out and the boy is in terror to see his cat get disembodied, **Uncle Grandpa tells the boy that the cat Aunt Grandma had wasn't really Pickles and that it was a robot**. The boy is happy to have the real Pickles and thanks Uncle Grandpa, he can't believe that Aunt Grandma tried to give him a fake Pickles, he's glad again that Uncle Grandpa came around and tells Uncle Grandpa that he should do this for a living. Uncle Grandpa thanks the kid and he states that it feels good to help again. And as for the fake Pickles, he believes that it's time to meet it's maker.